Next.js and PHP on Same Apache Server: Slow Loading with ProxyPass—How to Optimize?
I have deployed a Next.js application alongside a PHP application on the same Apache server. To route traffic to the Next.js app, I’m using ProxyPass. While everything is working, the Next.js application is loading extremely slowly compared to my local development environment.
My Current Apache Configuration:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/dist/"
    ServerName myapp.net
    ServerAlias *.myapp.net

    # Proxy configuration for Next.js
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyTimeout 60
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore
    ProxyIOBufferSize 65536

    # Serve static files directly
    Alias /static /var/www/myapp/static
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /static !
</VirtualHost>

Edit 1: I'm running nextjs project in dev mode using below command in screen.
npm run dev
Starting...
Ready in 5.7s
Found a change in next.config.mjs. Restarting the server to apply the changes...
Next.js 14.2.5
- Local:        http://localhost:3000
- Environments: .env
Starting...
Ready in 2.5s

Problems:

Slow Loading: The Next.js app is loading significantly slower in production compared to my local environment.
Performance Bottleneck: I’m concerned that ProxyPass might be causing performance issues, but I’m not sure how to improve it.
Gzip Compression: I’ve enabled Gzip compression, but I’m unsure if it’s properly optimized.

Questions:
Is there a better way to configure Apache for serving a Next.js app with ProxyPass?
What other optimizations can I apply to Apache to improve loading times?
Would it make sense to use a different reverse proxy like Nginx in this scenario?
Any advice or suggestions on how to improve the performance of my Next.js application in this setup would be greatly appreciated!

Can you please confirm how you are serving next js app. Like you are serving build or it running in dev mode like 'npm run dev'

Yes, I'm running in dev mode using "npm run dev"

Why kind of content is it you are serving from the nextjs app? What size? I have seen similar issues with large size responses that the proxy module had been unable to treat chunk wise, for example for compression. That means it first has to wait for the response to complete before being able to compress and forward the result.

Its not a good practice to running dev mode behind the apache proxy. Try to create a production build and serve it. Checkout it https://dev.to/aanis434/how-to-deploy-a-react-nextjs-application-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-in-aws-ec2-instance-221o

@PrinceKumarBarnwal Thanks for your suggestion, after switching to build and serve process, It actually helped now the site load normal.
